# Nodejs MySQL Query Blocks Request Module

Tags: mysql, node.js, httprequest

I'm a nodejs newbie and getting used to all the async stuff.

Using the:
 - Node-MySQL (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)
 - Request (https://github.com/mikeal/request)
modules right now.

I'm querying a big list of URLs (10,000 URLs) and trying to send them a HTTP GET request to get their HTTP statuses.

It works but the problem is, when I run the code, when each row from the MySQL query is returned, the processURL function is called, it logs the 'BEFORE' and 'AFTER' just after the each URL value, (as far as I can understand) sends the HTTP request, but waits for the MySQL query to complete before returning the HTTP statuses.

Simply, it can not check these URLs and return their results while the query is running. It waits for the query to complete to return the results of the HTTP requests.

This looks meaningless to me as it runs the processURL function when each row is streamed. Here is the full code:

```
var mysql       = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'urlDB',
});

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM urls LIMIT 10000');
query.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
query.on('result', function(row) {
    processURL(row.urlValue, function() {

    });
    console.log(row.urlValue);
})

function processURL (url){
    var request     = require('request');
    var startTime = new Date();
    console.log('BEFORE');
    request({
        uri: url,
        method: 'GET',
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log('INSIDE');
        var endTime = new Date();

        if (!error) {
            console.log(response.statusCode + '  Start: ' + startTime + '  End: ' + endTime);
        } else {
            console.log('timeout');
        }
    })
    console.log('AFTER');
}
```

The output is as below:
www.google.com
BEFORE
AFTER
www.yahoo.com
BEFORE
AFTER
www.cnn.com
BEFORE
AFTER
...but no 'INSIDE' until the query completes.

Any help is appreciated and thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your example to get results more slowly, and it works as expected. You can copy-paste to try:

```
var request = require('request');

var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com', 'http://ninjaturtles.com'];

getResultSlowly();

function getResultSlowly() {
  var result = urls.shift();
  if (!result) return;

  console.log(result);
  processUrl(result);
  setTimeout(getResultSlowly, 1000);
}

function processUrl(url) {
  var startTime = new Date();
  console.log('BEFORE');
  request({
    uri: url,
    method: 'GET',
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log('INSIDE');
    var endTime = new Date();

    if (!error) {
      console.log(response.statusCode + '  Start: ' + startTime + '  End: ' + endTime);
    } else {
      console.log('timeout');
    }
  })
  console.log('AFTER');
}
```

It's likely that network latency is just covering up the async behavior.

The results from your query will return near-instantly, firing several `result` events as soon as you execute your code. However, your `request` event will take quite a bit longer (even if just a millisecond or two) because it has to go make a connection with google or yahoo or whomever.

output:

```
$ node asynctest.js 
http://google.com
BEFORE
AFTER
INSIDE
200  Start: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:34 GMT-0500 (EST)  End: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:34 GMT-0500 (EST)
http://yahoo.com
BEFORE
AFTER
http://ninjaturtles.com
BEFORE
AFTER
INSIDE
200  Start: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:36 GMT-0500 (EST)  End: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:37 GMT-0500 (EST)
INSIDE
200  Start: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:35 GMT-0500 (EST)  End: Sat Dec 29 2012 11:31:38 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. But not exactly sure if that is the case (it can be too).
 
It takes ~15 seconds for the console.log() to print the urls from the query and no 'INSIDE' is printed during that.

However, I was wondering if this can be a performance issue with console.log() being sync.Although the updated code seems to work, it skips (understand that it can be the only text env. you have) the MySQL query part which can be the problematic part (which I also think is not).

Comment: Actually, while writing, your outcome sounds more reasonable.

Will come back with more tests.

Thanks so much again (and will happily accept the answer if that is the case).

Comment: The ~15s part sounds strange, it might be good to isolate that behavior with something that just console.log()s the results from the query... since the query itself should have no discernable delay (especially on localhost!).